# How do I disconnect two objects

Tags: mesh, objects, selection-tools

So I have this one torus which I copied to get another torus. I did this by clicking <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. But now, Blender treats the tori as if they were one entity. If I select one, the other is automatically selected. I'm assuming this happened because I didn't separate them immediately by clicking <kbd>P</kbd>.

How can I disconnect them now?

Comment: In edit mode you can try pressing 'L' to select one torus and then separate it by P. You can clarify ur question with a few pictures too

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: The reason they are treated as one entity is because you duplicated (part of / all of) the _mesh_, in Edit mode. To duplicate the _object_, do it in Object mode.